Query to return parents and parents of parents from two tables in Mysql
See the Fiddle for details
https://sqlfiddle.com/mysql/online-compiler?id=e59b8453-f19b-4ff0-83f9-75f44b22626b
I've reviewed the other recursive answers which do not seem to answer my question. I am essentially looking to create a table with multiple records for the same Value with it's entire 'lineage' so:



Value
Lineage




Great Great Grandson
Great Grandson


Great Great Grandson
Grandson


Great Great Grandson
Son


Great Great Grandson
Father


Great Grandson
Grandson


Great Grandson
Son


Great Grandson
Father


Grandson
Son


Grandson
Father


Son
Father


Father
-



In other words, I want to use a Child|Parent table to create another one with records for each of the Child's lineage, be it Parent or Parent of Paret.
In my case, I have a 'Product' Table with IDs and Names:



ProductID
Name




1
Fruits


2
Vegetables


3
Livestock


4
Apples


5
Granny Smith


6.
Beef


7
Steak


8
Ribeye



and then a Child/Parent table for the hierarchy:



ChildID
ParentID




4
1


5
4


8
7


7
6


6
3


..
...



I can do an Inner Join to return Child|Parent
Select F.Name as Child, F2.Name as Parent from Foods F 
Inner Join Parents P 
On F.ProductID=ChildID
Inner Join Foods F2
On F2.ProductID=ParentID

But I'm looking to create a new table with all of the Child Parents Names:



Child
Parents




Granny Smith
Apples


Granny Smith
Fruits


Apples
Fruits


RibeEye
Steak


RibEye
Beef


RibEye
Livestock


Steak
Beef


Steak
Livestock


Beef
Livestock




If you are in Mysql Version 8 or newer you can use a recursive CTE to solve: https://sqlfiddle.com/mysql/online-compiler?id=f75c0d30-16eb-4af1-88c2-e7a2bb469dec

@JNevill Thanks but yikes I'm in 5.6.51
